# Adding and synchronising audio file to a movie

Tags: replacement-parts, sound

Let’s consider the following working scenario: I have some movies with audio in one language, and I have some audio recordings of the same films, but in French. I want to replace the original audio track with this alternative soundtrack.

Can you tell me how can I do that? Do you know any free software which can help me? I assume that it is a lot of work with fitting and synchronizing.

I wish to learn French language, and I was thinking it might be a good idea to watch the movies with French dialogues.

Comment: @DrMayhem where is he breaking the law? And doesn't the law depend on the country he's in?

Comment: Have edited - hopefully this meets the requirements of the question, without pushing legal boundaries :-)

Comment: @DrMayhem: I'm serious when I said about learning French. This is a part of how I learned English. Subtitles are a must in learning process.

Answer (score 3):

Most pro video editors will let you strip the audio track off once you put the entire movie in the timeline. Once you have removed the original audio track you can add your French version. The first issue will be, how do you know where your new track and movie line up? Do both have sync marks? Are you absolutely certain that both the video and new audio tracks have perfect interval timing? If they don't, what might appear as in sync in the beginning will quickly become totally out of sync in the end.

You can download a trail version of Sony Vegas Pro and use it free for 30 days:

http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/download/trials/vegaspro

UPDATE:
If you choose Vegas Pro: Put your original movie on the timeline, right click the audio track, in the menu choose "Group" and next to that choose "remove from" then click the audio by itself, then right click and "Delete". This 'group remove from' action allows you to remove the association the video and audio have and thereby allow you to remove the audio.

The next issue will be, did you mean only the voice part? Were you expecting to just substitute the dialogue and keep the music and Foley from the original track? I won't even venture an answer on that part, sounds very tedious and expensive.

As far as the legality. As long as this is for your own viewing, I don't think you will need to worry about the legal part. However, should you show lots of people, or worse publish this on Youtube or something, then yes you can expect that the long arm of the law will reach out and quash it.

Quite honestly, I would just simply hire a very attractive translator and enjoy the movie with her.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a nice way to go about it not too mention allowing for some 'ooo la la'.

Answer (score 1):

Get Adobe Premier Pro. Grab the original video with the one language you have to the editing box. Right-click the video and click UNLINK. Now your video and your audio is already unlinked from each other. Click the Audio Box where the Original Audio was and delete it. Now Grab the French movie to another Box of the timeline. Right Click the French Version and click  UNLINK. Now that the french version is already unlinked, its time to click the video of the french version and delete it leaving you with the Video of the original version and the Audio of the french version. Then synch it based on your skills. If you need to get some audio or video from the original or the french, it is always there for you to grab and adjust just by cutting it using the blade sign located at the upper left side of the editor.

Comment: The link you have provided points to a studio, not Adobe's site.  Please correct the link.